# Why does iterating a mapped sorted stream evaluate more elements than necessary?

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider this small program, where we take a stream, sort it, map it, then iterate it:

```
public class AlphabetOrdinals {

    private static final List<Character> ALPHABET = List.of('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
    private static final int STOP_ORDINAL = 'b' - 'a';

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("java.runtime.version = " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));

        Stream<Integer> ordinals = ALPHABET.stream()
                                           .sorted()
                                           .map(AlphabetOrdinals::ordinal);

        int count = 0;

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = ordinals.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int ordinal = iterator.next();
            if (ordinal > STOP_ORDINAL) {
                System.out.println("stopping at " + ordinal);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("consuming " + ordinal);
            ++count;
        }

        System.out.println("consumed " + count + " ordinals");
    }

    private static int ordinal(char letter) {
        int ordinal = letter - 'a';
        System.out.println("performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of " + letter + " -> " + ordinal);
        return ordinal;
    }

}
```

This program is silly, but is simplified from a real program where the iteration is intertwined with an iteration over another stream, so i can't easily replace it with a takeWhile/forEach.

I would expect this program to print:

```
java.runtime.version = 11+28
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of a -> 0
consuming 0
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of b -> 1
consuming 1
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of c -> 2
stopping at 2
consumed 2 ordinals
```

But it prints:

```
java.runtime.version = 11+28
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of a -> 0
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of b -> 1
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of c -> 2
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of d -> 3
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of e -> 4
performing EXTREMELY EXPENSIVE mapping of f -> 5
consuming 0
consuming 1
stopping at 2
consumed 2 ordinals
```

If i remove the `.sorted()`, it prints what i expect.

Why does this happen?

In the real program, the mapping step involves reading a load of data from a slow network drive, so i am keen not to do it more times than absolutely necessary!

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes. That's what i want. So why does it perform the mapping on d, e, and f?

Comment: Sorting the List means it needs to consume the entire list first. The entire pipeline is processed in a single loop. So, the entire pipeline is evaluated first, and the result is buffered.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn but _why_? of course it consumes the entire List because of sort, why are _subsequent_ operations consuming the result of _sorted_ entirely?

Comment: If you change the source to be a `TreeSet`, it will only do the mapping for the first 3 elements.

Comment: Adding a `.takeWhile(o -> o <= STOP_ORDINAL)` will also yield the requested propertiy.

Comment: It's also possible to break the eagerness by doing `Stream.concat(sorted, Stream.empty())` before the mapping.

Answer (score 6):

Boring Answer:

This is just the way the streams API implementation was written.

Less Boring Answer:

A stream has some kind of chain of operations to apply to the input. For a stream of references the operation that gets added for sorting is: `java.util.stream.SortedOps.RefSortingSink` (assuming you have a similar JDK to me).
For map it is:

```
new StatelessOp<P_OUT, R>(this, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
                                     StreamOpFlag.NOT_SORTED | StreamOpFlag.NOT_DISTINCT) {
            @Override
            Sink<P_OUT> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<R> sink) {
                return new Sink.ChainedReference<P_OUT, R>(sink) {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(P_OUT u) {
                        downstream.accept(mapper.apply(u));
                    }
                };
            }
        };
```

The relevant parts of the implementation of `java.util.stream.SortedOps.RefSortingSink` are here:

```
  @Override
        public void begin(long size) {
            if (size >= Nodes.MAX_ARRAY_SIZE)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(Nodes.BAD_SIZE);
            list = (size >= 0) ? new ArrayList<T>((int) size) : new ArrayList<T>();
        }

        @Override
        public void end() {
            list.sort(comparator);
            downstream.begin(list.size());
            if (!cancellationWasRequested) {
                list.forEach(downstream::accept);
            }
            else {
                for (T t : list) {
                    if (downstream.cancellationRequested()) break;
                    downstream.accept(t);
                }
            }
            downstream.end();
            list = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(T t) {
            list.add(t);
        }
```

As you can see sorted passes on the entire list to the next operation in the chain(the next operation is called `downstream`). The map operation however takes anything it receives, uses the mapping function and passes it on to the downstream. This means that if you only use map you get the lazy expected behavior, while if you use sorted, the entire now sorted stream gets shoved down map's throat in `list.forEach(downstream::accept)`, and map can't refuse to take it, or only take part of it.

Comment: If you add `.takeWhile(o -> o <= STOP_ORDINAL)` after the mapping, it will not shove all elements down. Quite interesting. I guess, `cancellationWasRequested` is `true` in that case.

Comment: That would be my guess to, though worth noting that `takeWhile` is a java9 feature so availability may vary.

Comment: Debugging suggests `cancellationWasRequested` is set to true when a short-circuiting operation is in the pipeline. Not sure why this is not true for the iterator case.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn because it would be impossible to deduct in case of `iterator`, I guess.

Comment: It is impossible to deduct that it will not do that. There might be a reason behind why they did choose to err on the side "the iterator will always consume all entries".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn _I_ would have done that entirely in reverse, if you _are_ using an iterator you absolutely might terminate earlier; but it might be just me.

Comment: @Eugene Another reason: i don't think the behaviour we see can happen without allocating storage for the mapped list. A key reason to use streams and iterators is to avoid materialising the whole of a collection for intermediate steps!